# Tumblr v2 API accessing private blogs

Tags: api, private, tumblr

Have been searching high and low and cannot find any relevant answer on this.  I was wondering if anyone has come across the Tumblr API v2 call that will let you access data from a private blog.  I would like to post and retrieve listings from some of my private blogs while providing authentication of course.

Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible. The best source for this kind of information is the [Tumblr API user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/tumblr-api), if you ask there, there is at least the chance that tubmlr's developers will read it :)

Comment: thanks for the response, according to tunblr as well you are correct.  I will have a look at the user group thank you

Answer (score 5):

Using correct OAuth calls to the API, with an access Token for a private blog, it is possible to access at least *some* of that private blog's information with the Tumblr API v2.

Here are some observations I have made:

- api.tumblr.com/v2/**blog**/{base-hostname}/**posts**

  Normally you make this call with your Public API Key, and that allows you to access the posts of any Tumblr that is not private.

  ***However!***   **Good news**: If you include the **full OAuth headers** when making this request, it **will** return the list of posts of a Private Tumblr account. You need an access Token for that Tumblr, of course, to do this. Yes, I have tried this, done this, and it works.

  If you *only* use your consumer API key, e.g.

  ```
  api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{base-hostname}/posts?api_key=w8878374r384r...
  ```

  Then you will get nothing.   You have to make a fully-authenticated request with all of the proper OAuth parameters.
- api.tumblr.com/v2/**blog**/{base-hostname}/**info**

  Will *not* work at all for a private blog, even when using all the proper OAuth stuff to make the API call.
- api.tumblr.com/v2/**user/info**

  Normally this returns a list of "blogs" for the given authenticated user. However, any private tumblrs will *not* show up in this list of blogs.

*Note:*

- I have not tested many of the other API calls with private blogs, so I cannot tell you for sure if creating/editing/removing posts works or not.
- I have not tested this at all with xAuth, only regular OAuth and a standard access Token obtained through the "web authorization flow"

Comment: Hey Felix,
Thanks for detailed findings.  I am going to test out the Oauth route, and had always suspected this could work.  Will report back and accept.
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
$conskey = "CONSUMER KEY";
$conssec = "CONSUMER SECRET";

$tumblr_blog = "myblog.tumblr.com";
$to_be_posted = "This is the text to be posted";

$oauth = new OAuth($conskey,$conssec);
$oauth->fetch("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/".$tumblr_blog."/post", array('type'=>'text', 'body'=>$to_be_posted), OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST);

$result = json_decode($oauth->getLastResponse());

if($result->meta->status == 200){
  echo 'Success!';
}
```

Try the code above to post to your blog using API.

Hope that helps.

Comment: where do i get the `oAuth class`?  `$oauth = new OAuth($conskey,$conssec);`

Comment: oAuth can be installed in your server. It must also be enabled in your php.ini

see this link --> http://php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php