# How can I get posts from a password-protected tumblr using the API?

Tags: tumblr

I'm trying to use the tumblr API (http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2), but I don't see how to access another user's password protected blog. I have the password, but there doesn't appear to be any place to use it. The OAuth stuff doesn't help since that is the credentials for the user, not the blog.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Oauth in order to do this. You have to be Oauth authenticated before you can access password protected blogs, and you also need to be a member of the blog I believe and have a consumer API key.

See: [Tumblr v2 API accessing private blogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090257/tumblr-v2-api-accessing-private-blogs#11127423)

You could also try getting into contact with tumblr's support here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/tumblr-api (yeah, they use google groups >,>)